# Different provider paiement commission

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

Hello I'm David 29 years old, Freelancer and have a question concerning a transfert paiement method for one client.

My old Client want an e-shop. In this e-shop my client sell different product from different provider (italia, slovenia, croatia etc..) and for this my client just take 10% for each order.

**For exemple :**

a person take 2 product one pair of gloves and one hand cream. total of the cart 200.- (100.- each product) so it's 20.- for my client and 90.- for each provider and my client does not want to transfer every day the money for each provider he just need to take his commission and all other transfer are automatically.

If somebody know how to do that i'm really interested to understand and read your comments.

PS : for the moment his website is made with JS (VUE.JS) HTML CSS and a little bit of PHP.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a **marketplace payment platform**. These are commercial platforms that handle payment processing and allow paying out your users. Here's a few examples from companies I'd trust that appeared on the first page of a Google search when I searched for `marketplace payments platform`:

- [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect)
- [Braintree Marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-marketplace)
- [Adyen for Platforms](https://www.adyen.com/our-solution/marketplaces-and-platforms)

I haven't used any of these products personally and wouldn't know how to recommend one over another.

Comment: Thank you for our comment I'll see if stripe do thing like this.